# 2-line regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to make a search in text file for 2 lines of text (one is placed always after another). One line is always the same: `#EXTINF:Discovery Science`. However 2nd one is always different but has following pattern: "http://" ipaddress ":" some random port ip address ":" random port

Example:

```
#EXTINF:Discovery Science http://95.188.124.44:1234/udp/233.7.70.27:5000
```

Here is my code:

```
$file = "C:\1.m3u"
$Text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file) 
[regex]$reg = "([#EXTINF:Discovery Science http://\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b])"
$match = $reg.match($Text)  
$array = @()
$array = new-object collections.arraylist
$array = while ($match.Success)  
{            
    $match.Groups[1].value            
    $match = $match.nextMatch()
    write-host $match
}
```

Comment: You should remove `[` and `]` from the regex, otherwise it will be looking for 1 symbol that is defined in thus created character class. Also, the first `\b` is redundant, you can remove it (`//\d{1,3}`...)

Comment: I don't see a second line in your example text (or your regular expression), but the additional text `/udp/` between the first port and the second IP address. Also, you don't need to match word boundaries, so remove the `\b`.

Comment: Ah yes, there might be a linebreak! Then, to play it safe, I think you can use `(#EXTINF:Discovery Science\s+http://\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`. The `\s` matches any whitespace.

Comment: @Tensibai my original intent was to make the `#` appear, sorry about this.

Comment: I try not to assume. @filbrinza, please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to match any whitespace, you can use `\s+` (1 or more whitespace). Also, I assume the `#EXTINF:Discovery Science` text is known and thus there is no point in capturing it with a capturing group, and I suggest moving the `(` right before the `http`.

Another point is that `\b`s are redundant in this expression, and the worst part of it is the *character class* formed with `[...]`. Note that character class matches 1 symbol from the specified set of symbols inside the square brackets. You just need to remove them.

Here is a working demo returning `http://95.188.124.44`:

```
$Text = "#EXTINF:Discovery Science`r`nhttp://95.188.124.44:1234/udp/233.7.70.27:5000"
[regex]$reg = "#EXTINF:Discovery Science\s+(http://\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"
$match = $reg.match($Text)  
$array = @()
$array = new-object collections.arraylist
$array = while ($match.Success)  
{            
    write-host $match.Groups[1].value            
    $match = $match.nextMatch()
}
```

If you need to include the port number `:5000`, just add `:\d+` to the regex:

```
[regex]$reg = "#EXTINF:Discovery Science\s+(http://\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d+)"
```

If you just need to grab **1 or more non-whitespace symbols after `http`**, use:

```
[regex]$reg = "#EXTINF:Discovery Science\s+(http://\S+)"
```

Comment: We are almost there now I get :  #EXTINF:Discovery Science
h ttp://95.188.124.44:1234
Howevere still missing 2nd part of ip : /udp/233.7.70.27:5000

The end result should be : #EXTINF:Discovery Science h ttp://95.188.124.44:1234/udp/233.7.70.27:5000

Comment: Do you really need the regex to be that precise? I think all you need is `[regex]$reg = "#EXTINF:Discovery Science\s+(http://\S+)"`

Comment: I added this regex to the answer. Just note that if you need the text before the URL, you can just get it via `$match.value`, no need accessing Group1. Groups are necessary to access submatches, smaller chunks inside matched texts.